# creating two tables in Mysql where id's of second table must fallow first table?

Tags: mysql

I think this is not the right way to post. I have created tables in Mysql and i retrieved them properly. But now i got a problem for my application.

> What i need is The second table id's must fallow first table id's.For
>   example if the first table is having 5 products the id's will be
>   1,2,3,4,5. And I created second table where it contains three products
>   there Id's are 1,2,3.

But

> i need to get Second table id's as 6,7,8.

Can any suggest me .Actually i am new to mysql I don't know about all the queries. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's causing you to require splitting this table into two separate tables? IMO this is a symptom of problems with the design of your database.

Comment: Please post your current table schema and clearly explain why are you doing this what is your real goal

Comment: This two tables are different categories

Comment: If the data in both tables are products it probably would be best to store them in the same table and have another column to identify what category the product is in.  This column can be text or better a foreign key ID to a table with a list of categories.

Comment: @user2083041 *This two tables are different categories...* That didn't clear much. What id should be assigned if you want to insert new rows in table1?

Comment: I have solved my problem by hints of LukeS. Thankyou Lukes for your suggestion